# Execute a bash command in the text of a vim buffer

Tags: bash, vim

I know that I can get into bash while in vim via:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

or

```
:sh
```

or

```
:shell
```

etc.

Then use bash commands as normal, and get back out using `fg`.

What I am wondering is, can I execute a line of code from a script in vim straight to Bash, without having to exit vim, or having to copy it (via highlighting in visual mode for example) from vim, then going to a terminal and pasting it and hitting enter etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way is to put the cursor on the line and type:

`!!sh`<kbd>return</kbd>

This will replace the line with the output of the script.  If you don't want that, simply follow up with `u`.

Comment: Oh that is cool! I've drilled down in the vim docs to varying levels, but have not run into this one yet.

Comment: Thanks this is a very cool trick. Not exactly what I was going for but I will upvote it and keep it in mind. Does this physically execute the command in bash also? Or just show the output?

Comment: This is actually very smart, I like it!

Comment: @StatGenGeek It runs the command (`sh`) with the current line as stdin and replaces the line with the stdout of the command.  So, yes, it executes the command.

Comment: Note that if you really need to run it through `bash`, and if `sh` is not a link to `bash`, you can do `!!bash`

Comment: Ok thanks that does make sense now. Excellent I'll give this the answer tick thankyou.

Comment: Is there a way to use `:vs` and then in one buffer have code to edit and in the other run bash for execution ?

Answer (score 1):

Arguably easiest way:

1. Yank the text you want to execute.
2. Open the cmdline (by pressing <kbd>:</kbd>)
3. type `!` and then press `ctrl-r` and `"`, which will paste the content of the unnamed register to the cmdline (which will contain the text you wanted to execute)
4. press Enter